# SQL Query for getting data from different columns of different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset as following:

```
VN FNAME SEG         STARTTIME               ENDTIME          F1  DIS  F2 
5   try   1    09-DEC-21 10.00.00 PM  09-DEC-21 11.05.00 PM   0    2    1
1   eat   1    09-DEC-21 11.00.00 PM  09-DEC-21 11.59.59 PM   1   15    1 
5   sit   1    09-DEC-21 11.30.00 PM  09-DEC-21 11.59.59 PM   0   21    1
1   eat   2    10-DEC-21 12.00.00 AM  10-DEC-21 02.00.00 AM   1   15    1
5   sit   2    10-DEC-21 12.00.00 AM  10-DEC-21 04.00.00 AM   0   21    1
9   fly   1    10-DEC-21 01.00.00 AM  10-DEC-21 04.30.00 AM   1   50    1
4   say   1    10-DEC-21 05.00.00 AM  10-DEC-21 06.30.00 AM   0   25    1
```

With the above dataset I want to fetch records with unique `FNAME` where `F1` and `F2` both are 1 but `STARTTIME` displays the `STARTTIME` where `SEG = 1` and `ENDTIME` displays the `ENDTIME` where `SEG = max(SEG)` for the `FNAME`. So basically the result which I am looking at is:

```
VN FNAME      STARTTIME              ENDTIME             DIS  
1   eat   09-DEC-21 11.00.00 PM  10-DEC-21 02.00.00 AM    15
9   fly   10-DEC-21 01.00.00 AM  10-DEC-21 04.30.00 AM    50
```

How can I achieve this using a SQL query? The database I am working with is Oracle.

Any help appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any SQL yourself?

Comment: `@Nathan_Sav` As a matter of fact I have. I tried solving it by using rowid, also tried rank()  but since I am a beginner , I got lost and couldnt find a way out. I can do it using PL/SQL but using SQL query seems difficult to me. I am able to fetch START and ENDTIMES from same row but usecase is such that STARTTIME should be the one where  SEG is minimum (i.e. 1) and ENDTIME should be the one where SEG is maximum for a FNAME.

Comment: Have you tried group by with `count` and `max` and using `having count(*)=1`

Comment: `@Nathan_Sav` No i have not tried this. Can you please help with the query?

Comment: `select
t.fname,
(select t2.starttime from table1 as t2 where t2.fname=t.fname and t2.seg=1) as start_time,
(select max(t3.endtime) from table1 as t3 where t3.fname=t.fname) as end_time,
from 
table1 as t
where t.f1=1 and t.f2=1
group by fname
having count(*)=1`   I've not tested

Comment: `@Nathan_Sav` This works with a minor tweak which is putting count(*) >= 1 in the having clause. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like so, using grouing and subqueries.  Having count(*) as 1 will show where there is 1 instance of the name, with F1 & F2 being 1.

```
select t.fname, 
(select t2.starttime from table1 as t2 where t2.fname=t.fname and t2.seg=1) as start_time, 
max(t.endtime) as end_time
 from table1 as t 
where t.f1=1 and t.f2=1 
group by t.fname 
having count(*)=1
```